# Varaiable does not update after For Loop

Tags: c, string, for-loop

Here I have written a simple encryption function. 
The variable somehow starts with an unexpected value and remains the same after the For Loop.

The code is right below:

```
int sim_encrypt( char* PreEncMsg , int spaces) {
    
    int MsgLen = strlen(PreEncMsg);
    int PostEncMsg = 0;
    
    for (int iter1 = 0; iter1 < 3; iter1++) {
        for (int iter2 = 0; iter2 < MsgLen; iter2++) {  //Get every 4 character in the string
            if (iter2 % spaces == 0) {
                printf("[PROCCESS|%d] = %d\n", iter1 + 1 ,PreEncMsg[iter2]);
                int PostEncMsg = PostEncMsg + PreEncMsg[iter2];
                printf("Encrypted code = [%d]\n" , PostEncMsg);
            }
        }
        memmove(PreEncMsg, PreEncMsg+1, MsgLen);  //Removes the first chracter of the string
    }
    printf("Final result = [%d]\n" , PostEncMsg);
    return PostEncMsg;
}
```

The following is the output

```
[PROCCESS|1] = 72
Encrypted code = [21931]
.
.
.
[PROCCESS|3] = 116
Encrypted code = [23293]
[PROCCESS|3] = 0
Encrypted code = [23293]
Final Result = [0]
```

As you can see the "PostEncMsg" was first assigned as "0" but somehow starts with "21858". 
And in the final result, the variable is somehow "0".

Comment: Likely *Undefined Behavior* elsewhere in your code, Please provide [A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: `memmove(PreEncMsg, PreEncMsg+1, MsgLen);` That looks dangerous. It tries to read `MsgLen` characters starting from `PreEncMsg+1` but that seems like it may go past the end of the `PreEncMsg` buffer.

Comment: @kaylum, at first glance I thought the same thing, but the buffer holds null character at the end, which gets picked up by the memmove and effectively drags the terminator along as the string characters are shifted left.

Comment: So, the loops will eventually be processing zero byte values btw. I suspect that for correct operation, you really want to track where the terminal null byte is as you iterate through those loops, so you can terminate at the correct point. Each time you call `memmove`, decrement `MsgLen`. One bug at a time.

Comment: So should i replace `memmove` with something more secure or somehow decrement `MsgLen`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of the `PostEncMsg` variable inside the loop

```
int PostEncMsg = PostEncMsg + PreEncMsg[iter2];
```

*eclipses* the one at the beginning of the function

```
int PostEncMsg = 0;
```

So basically you define a new variable at each loop iteration, and that's why the outer variable ("Final result") is not updated. The strange nembers you see in the inner `printf`s depend on the fact you never initialized the inner variable (so that its initial value is *undefined*).

I've not analyzed in depth what your function is supposed to do, but you probably just need to update  `PostEncMsg` variable inside the loop in this way

```
PostEncMsg = PostEncMsg + PreEncMsg[iter2];
```

Comment: After I removed the int declaration, the program delivered the desired results. Thank you!